# Capturing HTML5 Form Data and Translating that to a PostgresQL Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to accomplish the following but cannot for the life of me get the process to work correctly.

I have an HTML5 form that is acting as a 'sign-up' form for my app.  Technologies I am using are Sinatra for my routes, Active Record for database modeling and Ruby as my programming language of choice.  I am using PostgresQL as my backend database manager.

I would like to capture user sign-up information (name, email, password, phone number) and translate that to my PostgresQL backend database.  Currently, when I fill out the form and hit 'submit' a new record is being recorded in PostgresQL but no information is coming over with it.  Below is the code I currently have that I am using to attempt to accomplish this process:

**HTML5 Form**

```
    <h2>Sign-Up Form</h2>

<form action="/session/sign_up" method="post">

  <% if @user.present? && @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="integer" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  </div>
  <div id="submitbutton">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**Main app.rb file (Sinatra Routes)**

```
    post "/session/sign_up" do
    @email = params["email"]
    @password = params["password"]
    @password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(@password)

    user = User.create

    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect("/users")
end
```

**ActiveRecord User Model**

```
require 'bcrypt'
require_relative '../db/connection'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :plans
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      return self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end
  end
end
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!  I've google'd, read the ActiveRecord docs, and so on and cannot decipher what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the data to be used on the creation to the `.create` method as described on the [documentations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class#docs_body).

In your case you should use

```
data = params.permit(:email, :password)
user = User.create(data)
```

and then encrypt the password inside the user with a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
before_save :encrypt_password
```

you also may need to define `password` if `encrypted_password` is what you probably have on the database

```
attr_accessor :password
```

so your class will have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_password
  attr_accessor :password

  # all other stuff
end
```

Comment: If you want to know about the `permit` method, look into https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values

Comment: thank you so much for the speedy reply, i really appreciate it.  i will test what you have suggested and go from there.  once again, thank you very!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saving an empty User object without setting attributes based on the incoming form parameters.

(Typically you instantiate an AR object with the incoming params, or assign them individually.)